# can a button be used without a listener on android app?

Tags: android

I have recieved code for an android application 
unfortunately , the person who wrote the program is unreachable.

my problem is, in a certain activity there is a button but I can't find the listener for that button. it's like it doesn't exist and yet the app is running ok with that button.

the button is a button to move next . i have searched all sources for the button id but couldn't find it. only found it in the layout xml. how is that possible?

I have tried debugging it , and while I press that button the code jumps to the other activity's class so I can't seem to find what happens when I press that button!

the thing is there is a bug that happens as soon as I press the button (some global variable changes) and so I need to analyze what is happening when the button is pressed.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: show your class here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a click listener method in XML with

```
android:onClick="methodName"
```

and the corresponding

```
public void methodName(View view)
```

in your activity will get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the android xml, where that button has been defined in. It will have an `onClick` property associated with that button, where a method name would have been mentioned. So as soon as the button is clicked, that method will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We can use button without listener, for Example  in Layout file:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ported"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ported"

            android:onclick="test" />
```

You can get called this method in activity whenever you pressed that test button

```
public void test(View view)
{

// Your code
}
```